# Access Add-On SDK 'main' from XUL

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

In my add-on, I'm using XUL to display dialog windows because I can customize their appearance to suit the add-on's general style (like a custom `titlebar`).

Using the [migration guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/XUL_Migration_Guide#XUL_Windows), I'm able to do this easily. The thing is, I would like to call certain functions in the add-on's `main` module from the XUL dialog.

After a bit of searching I found the [`loader` module](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/_loader), which seems to be able to do exactly what I want. But, I'm experiencing trouble in using it to access the `main` module.

First, I tried the obvious approach as mentioned in the documentation;

**xul_dialog.js**:

```
let {Loader} = Components.utils.import('resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js');
let loader = Loader.Loader({
    paths: {
        'toolkit/': 'resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/',
        '': 'resource:///modules/',
        './': 'resource://<my-addon-name>/root/'
    }
});

let main = Loader.main(loader, './main');
```

I got an error that `'./main'` was not found at `resource://<my-addon-name>/root/`. Figuring that I was using the incorrect paths, I experimented a bit until I could remove all path associated errors.

**xul_dialog.js**:

```
let {Loader} = Components.utils.import('resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js');
let loader = Loader.Loader({
    paths: {
        'toolkit/': 'resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/',
        '': 'resource://gre/modules/commonjs/',
        './': 'resource://<my-addon-id>-at-jetpack/<my-addon-name>/lib/'
    }
});

let main = Loader.main(loader, './main');
```

This time I got a rather confusing error at `loader.js, line 279`.

```
Components is not available in this context.
Functionality provided by Components may be available in an SDK
module: https://jetpack.mozillalabs.com/sdk/latest/docs/

However, if you still need to import Components, you may use the
`chrome` module's properties for shortcuts to Component properties:

Shortcuts:
    Cc = Components.classes
    Ci = Components.interfaces
    Cu = Components.utils
    CC = Components.Constructor
Example:
    let { Cc, Ci } = require('chrome');
```

I get the same error when I use `Loader.Require(loader, {id: './main'})` instead of `Loader.main`. I even tried passing `Components` as `globals` when instantiating the loader, but without much luck.

I'm fairly certain that I'm doing a lot of things wrong. I don't understand why I'm getting the error, even after spending quite a bit of time in `loader.js`. Plus, I also think that there would be a better alternative than having to use the add-on id for the path to `main.js`; hard-coding it like that doesn't seem right.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have to do is to find a specific instance of `Loader`, not create a new one.

At main.js

```js
const { id, name, prefixURI } = require("@loader/options");
//pass these to the XUL dialog
```

At xul.js (or whatever is the name of the xul dialog script)

```
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm");
var extensionscope = XPIProvider.bootstrapScopes[id];
var mainjssandbox = extensionscope.loader.sandboxes[prefixURI + name + "/lib/main.js"];
```

Assuming there is a `foo` function at main.js, you can call it like

```
 mainjssandbox.foo();
```

Of course don't expect things to work as if XUL and Add-on SDK actually blended into one thing.

Comment: Can't stress enough, we did not design these apis to work with XUL, here be dragons, etc.

Comment: @canuckistani @paa I understand that, I just need a way for the dialog to communicate with the `main` module, which would handle the rest. I suppose if passing arguments to the dialog is the only way, I might as well pass the message receiving module. Would be much cleaner.

Comment: @Rikonator Pass a reference to `require` to your add-on then and properly and but your public functions into `export` then. Or just pass any reference to a `function`. Or pass the global scope.

Answer (score 1):

If it is **your** XUL dialog that should interact with **your** add-on, then please don't use the `Loader` stuff and in particular do not go the `XPIProvider.bootstrapScopes` @paa suggested. While this might work (for now), it should be noted that it relies on tons of implementation details that are subject to change at any point making this solution extremely fragile.

Instead there are a couple of other options (not an exhaustive list):

- If the SDK part opens the windows, you may use `.openDialog` which supports passing arguments to the created window, and these arguments can even be objects and functions. Also, you can have the window dispatch (custom) events, and which your SDK part can listen to by calling `addEventListener` on the `window` the `.openDialog` call returns.
- If the window is created from somewhere else (e.g. from the `AddonManager` because of `em:optionsURL`) then the [`nsIObserverService`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIObserverService) is another way to communicate. The window could e.g. `.notifyObservers` on `DOMContentLoaded` containing a reference to itself. The SDK parts would just have to observe such notifications by `addObserver`.
- Another way, a bit hacky but working, is the SDK part listening to new windows via [`nsIWindowWatcher.registerNotification`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIWindowWatcher) and then injecting some API into e.g. `browser.xul` windows by `XPCNativeWrapper.unwrap(subject.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIDOMWindow)).myAddonAPI = something`.

Be sure to handle unloading or your add-on well - it is still restartless -, i.e. reverse any changes you've done and remove any observers and so on again.

If you want to interact with SDK addons not created by you, then the `XPIProvider` route might be the only feasible. But still, it might be worth contacting the add-on author first asking for the addition of some public API instead of hacking deep into the AddonManager and SDK loader internals.

*PS:*

Considering passing `require` or the global scope to your window via `openDialog` if you want to. Get the global scope by placing this into your `main.js`:

```
const globalScope = this;
```

Comment: I think passing an object as an argument is the best way to go. But, instead of the global scope, I'm passing only the object that I wish the dialog to have access to. Much cleaner and much safer.